# Model of road disturbance in term of normal force

Tags: forces, acceleration, differentiation

According to this article [Channe, S.S. and Kshirsagar, S.D., *Modeling and Simulation of a Suspension System for Different Road Disturbances*](http://www.ijsr.net/conf/NCKITE2015/28.pdf), the best model for disturbance of a road is in the form of sine. It recommends a displacement almost like this picture. (I only changed 0.45m to 0.5 m due to simple calculations)

[image: Sine wave of road disturbance(up/down displacement)]

Assume that we have a car that moving on this road with speed v. To find period of this disturbance according to this formula:

```
v=x/t
```

our period T can be calculated as:

```
T=x/v=1(m)/v.
```

Then to create the vertical displacement we have:

```
y=A*sin(2*pi/T*t)=-0.1*sin(2*pi*v*t)
```

Then to find normal force caused by disturbance we should find second derivate of above equation. So we get:

```
y''=0.1*(2*pi*v)^2*sin(2*pi*v*t)
```

And the force can be calculated like below:

```
F_disturbance=y''*m
```

According to another article we simulate 1/4 of a car. Assume that 1/4 of a car mass is m=440 and a normal speed is v=40. So assuming pi^2=~10 we have:

```
F_disturbance=1408000*sin(2*pi*40*t)
```

So it says the max. disturbance of car is more than 1M while a car's own normal force assuming g=10 is F=m*g=440*10=4400 and at it's most it is 5K. So how a disturbance can be 1M/5K=200 times of its own?!!!

Please help me if i have wrong calculations.

Comment: confirming that 0.95m aproximates to 1m in your second equation?

Comment: This time varying model of the disturbance
$y=A*\sin(2*pi/T*t)$
needs to be damped, modulated usually by an e^-t factor

Comment: It's a massive help in physics calculations to always quote units immediatly after numbers; to avoid unit incompatibility errors. e.g. is v=40 mph or 40km/s or is it 40m/s?
All the units need to be SI for the calculation to work without correction factors.

Comment: F=ma, for sure, but you are describing the motion of the road, not the car, you should not use the mass of the car in this equation because it is the road that is being disturbed. The car does not oscillate up and down. I think that might be it, unless there is another mistake somewhere

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. What exactly are you trying to find out? What do you mean by "road disturbance"?

Comment: I second @sammygerbil 's suggestion that you make your question clear. Your calculations seems to say that if a car moves at constant speed on a road with sinusoidal bumps of constant wavelength then it will suffer acceleration in vertical direction. From this force on the car has been calculated. So what exactly is your confusion?

Comment: In my work I'm ignoring suspension system of the car and I only work on tire/mass model besides friction.
About units yes I almost use SI units and for sure velocity is v=40 m/s.
About velocity decrease you are right. The deceleration is a=-2 m/s^2 for example. But with considering this, the disturbance is high again.

Comment: Road disturbances mean uncertainties of road. Bumps, holes and other non-flat phenomena of the road.
The model suggested to model this disturbances. I want to use a model of road disturbances in terms of normal force not the vertical displacement.
I know it lacks something when u don't consider suspension system (that has damping, etc)

Could you offer me a more real model instead of this?

Comment: Further comments : 1. The normal force $N$ is *normal to the surface*, not vertical. Perhaps you are using the approximation that the horizontal component of $N$ is negligible?  2. Is vehicle speed constant throughout, or does it decrease as its height increases (such that KE+PE is constant)?  3. You seem to be assuming that the vehicle is a point mass. If not, I think the size of the wheelbase compared with the wavelength of the ripples in the road might be important.  4. If the vehicle is travelling fast enough, it will leave contact with the road at the top of each hump.

Comment: I think I now understand that you are trying to find how the normal force on the vehicle varies with time, but I still wonder what final goal you have for this project? It does not affect the answer for the normal force, but it does affect comments about this approach. For example, as JMLCarter says, ignoring vehicle suspension is not realistic, and this will interact with normal force from the road, so you cannot deal with these 2 effects separately - except possibly in the approximation of a very stiff suspension.

Comment: I ignore it because suspension by itself is not my goal, though the friction and suspension are coupled. I only want a simple and general disturbance in terms of normal force to check my model and controller for friction part only.

Answer (score 0):

Note: see my other answer. This first attempt is pending deletion.

F=ma, for sure, but you are describing the motion of the road, not the car, you should not use the mass of the car in this equation because it is the road that is being disturbed. The car does not oscillate up and down.
You should add some damping (or only consider the force at t=0), and estimate the mass of the affected element of road.

Comment: There is no way the road will "move up and down" in that manner, unless you are driving the car when an earthquake occurs! Since the OP says the suspension is being ignored, the *car* is performing simple harmonic motion in the vertical direction. Damping, exponential factors, etc, are irrelevant for that model. (Of course the a model that leaves out the car suspension is not very realistic, but the OP's is free to make whatever assumptions he/she likes).

Comment: yes way! (that's my view)  

It's heavily damped I doubt it would cycle once. The question itself has choosen this curve shape for time varying disturbance. It's a model, it will have limits.  

Indeed the model is not very realistic - but let me put it to you this way. did you notice how at the moment it is trying to describe road disturbance without any parameter describing any physical characteristics of the road surface? Humble request for a careful re-think.

Comment: me too, I'am thinking that the time varying oscilation after the vehicle has passed s not the significant effect in terms of road stress. It's probably negligible. Therefore  we should be modelling the tyre disturbance as a fixed curve even though it is a sin wave shaped curve it would be "forced" rather than harmonic. Which must be wt this model is intending all along.

Comment: So that means that one error would be failure to multiply by dt in the final equation. dt being v/d =1/40.
Also that the maximum force is not applied for all that time, it has to be an integral of the acceleration from t=0 to t=v/d by dt. Which I could latex, but I got an interrupt.
Thank you for your comment @alephzero

Comment: ok this is a different answer. It's probably about 1/120th of the original figure (pi is 3, dt is 1/40), it's still larger than the weight of the vehicle by a factor of about 2.5, much better though. Suggests your road distortion is more like 4cm than 10cm. OK, will post as another answer so it can be at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is modelling the tyre disturbance as a fixed curve even though it is a sin wave shaped curve it would be "forced" (and not harmonic).

The final term therefore needs two changes
1) multiplication by dt, which is 0.95/40 or aprox 1/40
2) use of the mean force not the max, given by the integral of the sin wave over the tyre indentation, i.e. from t=0 to t=1/80. (the hump in front of the tyre is a side effect of this distortion.) This introduces a factor of pi/4=.8 ish.

Therefore you can multiply the force of concern from without these corrections by 1/50.

Which is better, the force is now 28000. There are still a discrepancy of a factor of about 6 to 7.
You can tweak the model to compensate, either choose a lorry which is about 7 times heavier than a car or reduce the displacement of the road from 0.1 to match, depending upon what you are trying to get out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the wave relationship

$$\text{(speed)} = \text{(frequency)} \text{(wavelength)} $$

$$ v = \left(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\right) \lambda $$

where $ \lambda = \text{(wavelength)} = 1.0\text{ m}$ and speed $v$ in $\text{m/s}$.

This makes the displacement as

$$ y = Y \sin \left( \tfrac{2\pi v}{\lambda} t \right) $$

And its derivatives

$$ \dot{y} = Y \left( \tfrac{2\pi v}{\lambda} \right) \cos \left( \tfrac{2\pi v}{\lambda} t \right) $$

$$ \ddot{y} = -Y \left( \tfrac{2\pi v}{\lambda} \right)^2 \sin \left( \tfrac{2\pi v}{\lambda} t \right) $$

If you can find the effective mass over the wheel $m_w$ then

$$ F_w = m_w \ddot{y} $$

But the calculation for effective mass isn't straight forward as just using corner weights. Two things are important. The vehicle as a rigid body responds to a wheel impulse with translation and rotation (lowering the effective mass) and the overall suspension design prescribes the kinematics of the system (increasing the effective mass). This whole subject warrants a new question IMHO.