# Equations of Motion for a Passive Suspension System

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I am trying to develop the equations of motion for a passive suspension system. The system consists of one mass connected to another mass via a spring and dampener system, and then the bottom mass is connected to the road via the tire which is modeled as a spring. I'm not sure where the force applied to the system is, but I think it has something to do with the surface of the road and then the this is somehow related to the tire spring.

Comment: Your statement of the problem is too vague.   Also, we don't know your level of comfort with mechanics to know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct : the force is supplied by the bumps in the road.

The shape of the bumps and the speed of the vehicle produce a time-varying compression $x$ of the tire. The compression force is related to the compression $x$ and spring constant $k$ of the tire by $F=kx$. This force $F$ is transmitted to the masses in the system. Because of inertia they resist changes in motion.

See the following questions for further help with developing a model :

[Model of road disturbance in term of normal force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301164)
["Magic" Speed to Drive Over a Speed Bump: Myth or Reality?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136102)